# need sql query for the below scenario

Tags: sql, t-sql

table contains :

```
c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
da1  Null Null db1  dc1
da1  dx1  Null db1  dc1
da1  Null dy1  db1  Null
```

all are `varchar` fields.

i need a query which results data without any nulls and in a single row
"`da1 dx1 dy1 db1 dc1`"

Comment: What sql-server version?

Comment: Homework? Have you tried anything?

Comment: What if you have different values on one column? All NULL values?

Answer (score 4):

```
select 'da1', 'dx1', 'dt1', 'db1', 'dc1' from thattable limit 1
```

should work perfectly

Comment: +1, definitely should work, and Why didn't any one think about this!

Answer (score 3):

With the details delivered:

```
select max(c1), max(c2), max(c3), max(c4), max(c5)
from yourtable;
```

See [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67035) a simulation by MGA.

Comment: +1, you was faster, I deleted mine , this is a working demo add it to your answer: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67035.

Comment: Nice link, thanks. I'm sure it works, but it is hilarious: what problem is this? He doesn't give us all the requirements, i think...

Comment: There is no hilarious than the below answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191475/need-sql-query-for-the-below-scenario/10191637#10191637

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from (select distinct c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 from mytable) as mytab where c1 is not null and c2 is not null and c3 is not null and c4 is not null and c5 is not null
```